# Adding directories to MANPATH and INFOPATH

Tags: texlive

Texlive is asking me to add some directories to `MANPATH` and to `INFOPATH`.  How do I do that?

Most importantly, I have to add `/home/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux`
to my `PATH` for current and future sessions.

Comment: This is all documented in the document that was linked in your last question see https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html **Post-install: setting PATH**

Comment: `PATH=/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`.  Does the same apply to  `MANPATH` and to `INFOPATH`?

Comment: you do not want `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:` that is the default location but apparently you have installed it at `/home/hagbard/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/` so you just want `export PATH=/home/hagbard/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH ` in `.bash_profile` or whatever login file your linux setup uses (then log out and log in)

Comment: it does, although I never actually bother setting manpath or infopath, all the tex documentation is available from `texdoc`  which just needs PATH

Comment: I think it is good now. Doing `hagbard@fuckup:~$ tex --version` gives
`TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.`